# Generate pairs based on measurement and grouped by ID

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, calculated-columns

I have a dataset that includes various measurements of toys, with `Piece_ID` being a unique toy set and `Colour` being the colour of a specific toy in a set (let's use Lego pieces as an example).

I need to generate a new column, `Pairs`, based on `Length_mm` measurements by unique `Piece_ID` and `Colour` groups. Essentially, I want to consider Lego pieces a pair if they are in the same set, are the same colour, and the length of both pieces are within 2 mm of each other. However, if the colour is listed as "unknown", I do not want these to be paired, as this could be pairing two different colours. Pairs can only be of two.

The goal is to have a new column, `Pair`, where pairs are numbered sequentially in each piece set.

Here is an example of my dataset:

```
table <- "Piece_ID Width_mm   Length_mm  Colour
1  A     1.68 3.19 Unknown
2  A     1.47 2.88 Blue
3  A     1.64 2.90 Blue
4  A     1.80 3.20 Unknown
5  B     1.76 3.12 Red
6  B     1.61 3.11 Red
7  B     1.57 3.51 Blue
8  B     1.48 3.54 Blue
9  A     1.46 4.05 Green
10 A     1.83 4.03 Green
11 A     1.83 4.11 Green
12 A     1.83 4.51 Green
13 A     1.83 4.12 Green
14 A     1.83 3.55 Blue
15 A     1.83 3.57 Blue
16 A     1.83 3.55 Blue"

#Create a dataframe with the above table
df <- read.table(text=table, header = TRUE)
df
```

In this case, the output would be:

```
table2 <- "Piece_ID Width_mm   Length_mm  Colour Pair
1  A     1.68 3.19 Unknown 1
2  A     1.47 2.88 Blue 2
3  A     1.64 2.90 Blue 2
4  A     1.80 3.20 Unknown 3
5  B     1.76 3.12 Red 1
6  B     1.61 3.11 Red 1
7  B     1.57 3.51 Blue 2
8  B     1.48 3.54 Blue 3
9  A     1.46 4.05 Green 4
10 A     1.83 4.03 Green 4
11 A     1.83 4.11 Green 5
12 A     1.83 4.51 Green 6
13 A     1.83 4.12 Green 5
14 A     1.83 3.55 Blue 6
15 A     1.83 3.57 Blue 7
16 A     1.83 3.55 Blue 6"

#Create a dataframe with the above table
pairs <- read.table(text=table2, header = TRUE)
pairs
```

I thought an `ifelse` statement may work here, but I'm not sure how to exclude unknowns and how to consecutively number "pairs", where even unmatched pairs are given a number.

Edit: Added more data to show discrepancies.

Comment: Why are `3.51 Blue` and `1.48 3.54` not in the same `Pair`? They are within 2 mm `Length_mm` of each other

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann These are not within 2 mm, 3.51 and 3.54 are 3 mm apart.

Answer (score 1):

```
table <- "Piece_ID Width_mm   Length_mm  Colour
1  A     1.68 3.19 Unknown
2  A     1.47 2.88 Blue
3  A     1.64 2.90 Blue
4  A     1.80 3.20 Unknown
5  B     1.76 3.12 Red
6  B     1.61 3.11 Red
7  B     1.57 3.51 Blue
8  B     1.48 3.54 Blue
9  A     1.46 4.05 Green
10 A     1.83 4.03 Green"

#Create a dataframe with the above table
df <- read.table(text=table, header = TRUE)

df$pair <- Inf
df$pair[[1]] <- 1
df$abs_diff <- NA 
seen_vec <- character(0)
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){

 if(i!=1) {
   df$abs_diff[[i]] <- round(abs(df$Length_mm[[i]]-df$Length_mm[[i-1]]),2)
   if(! df$Piece_ID[[i]] %in% seen_vec) {
     df$pair[[i]] <- 1
     seen_vec <- c(seen_vec,df$Piece_ID[[i]])
   } else 
   if(
      df$Colour[[i]]!=df$Colour[[i-1]] 
    ){
     df$pair[[i]] <-    df$pair[[i-1 ]]  + 1 
   } else if( df$abs_diff[[i]]>0.02){
     df$pair[[i]] <-    df$pair[[i-1 ]]  + 1 
   } else 
     {
     df$pair[[i]] <-    df$pair[[i-1 ]]
   }

 } else {
   seen_vec <- df$Piece_ID[[i]]
 }
}
df
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to take into account if there are multiple possibilities? For example, if there is length 3.51, 3.51, and then 3.53, it should pair the two that are closest. Also, sometimes the colour and length combinations that should be matched are not directly below each other, so this method would not work for those cases (i-1). Is there a way to work around this besides sorting the data? I have edited my question to show this example.

Comment: This code also makes multiple pairs, if there are 3 pieces within 0.02 mm, these all become one "pair" of three